# Turing Machine for the Language $L=\{(a^n)b(a^n)b(a^n) | n\geq0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, lambda-calculus, computation-models

Turing Machine for the Language $L=\{(a^n)b(a^n)b(a^n) | n\geq0\}$

Here is what I have **tried**:

**1. Starting State**
Read $a$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **2**
Read $x$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **1**
Read `Bottom`, Go to State `YES`.

**2. Looking for $ab$**
Read $b$, Write $b$, Move Right, Go To **3**
Read $a$, Write $a$, Move Right, Go To **2**

**3. Middle Segment**
Read $a$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **4**
Read $x$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **3**

**4. Looking for $ab$**
Read $b$, Write $b$, Move Right, Go To **5**
Read $a$, Write $a$, Move Right, Go To **4**

**5. Last Segment**
Read $a$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **6**
Read $x$, Write $x$, Move Right, Go To **5**

**6. Back to Beginning**
Read $x$, Write $x$, Move Left, Go To **6**
Read $a$, Write $a$, Move Left, Go To **6**
Read $b$, Write $b$, Move Left, Go To **6**
Read `Bottom`, Write `Bottom`, Move Right, Go To **1**

However the problem is that it Accepts the Empty String  but the Smallest Acceptable Input is $bb$. Please help in resolving the issue.

> **Implicit Information**
>
> - `Bottom` means `Blank Symbol`, often denoted by `B`
> - `Starting State` means $q_o$
> - $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ (Input Alphabet)
> - $T = \{a,b,x,Bottom\}$ (Tape Alphabet)
> - `YES` means `Accept State`

Comment: Hint: What happens if the TM is in state 2 or 4 and finds a blank symbol? Or rather what should it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the start state, since your TM will accept when its `Bottom`, which from your explanation is `Blank`. That should be the reason for the TM accepting an empty input. Also, you do not have any means for checking a $bb$ input at the start.